# textView position for slidedown menu

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

## Xamarin Android

I'm trying make slidedown menu.
I don't know, what i'm doing wrong.

I can't position textView like i want.
View should be on the top of screen. However, it's on the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:background="#f2f2f2">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/productTitleBar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="#ff46a1e1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProductTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Product List"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Desription goes here"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnImgExpander"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnImgExpander"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/up_arrow"
    android:background="#fff2f2f2" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/productListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have

[image: What i have]

I want

[image: What i want]

Someone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Which one? You have two...

Comment: id: txtDescription ,btnImgExpander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:layout_above="@+id/btnImgExpander"` is set on the TextView, but `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` is set on the ImageView, which is aligning it to the bottom of the container (the outer RelativeLayout). You could try: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and remove the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`